# cyrus Imapd deliver -e, what does the -e?

Tags: postfix, cyrus

I asked myself what the -e Option in the Cyrus program deliver does. 
E.G. the -e is used in the postfix Configuration in master.cf, but I cannot find any reference to a -e option in the manpages of deliver.

Does anyone know what this option exactly does?

Heres a master.cf line from postfix. Alle other Options are clear to me except the -e

```
cyrus       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe    flags=R
  user=cyrus      argv=/usr/sbin/cyrdeliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
```

I know using lmtp is far better than cyrus deliver, I only used this as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it does nothing.

The source of deliver.c from cyrus-imap 2.1.18 includes this in option handling:

```
    case 'e':
        /* duplicate delivery. ignore */
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question this one but found it looking for some related matters.

It may be for backwards compatibility. After deprecating the -e option, but keeping it as a dummy input parameter to avoid 'unknown option' errors.

I think it was related to the already obsolete mail address ("+") extensions, but don't know how it worked for cyrdeliver before. About 2012 they were formally deprecated (just a while before you asked this)

Old news about using address extensions with Gmail can be found about 2008: https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html